# Dropdown list inside a datagrid

Tags: javascript

I am working with a dropdown list that is inside a datagrid. I am binding data to the dropdown list using a dataset. Here is the use case:  I select a particular value in a dropdown list from the next row onwards and I select the same value in the other rows of the dropdown list, which causes a message to be displayed.

How do I achieve this by using javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that each dropdown has a unique ID specified: `<select id="dropdown1">` etc:

```
var dd1 = document.getElementById('dropdown1');
var dd2 = document.getElementById('dropdown2');

if(dd1[dd1.selectedIndex].value == dd2[dd2.selectedIndex].value)
{
 alert("Dropdown 2 is the same value as dropdown1 !!!");
}
```